# Print item from QDomNodeList with QT

Tags: c++, xml, qt, rss, feed

I've called NYT xml url:
http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml

and i received 39 records that I put in QDomDocument.
So how to get the properties from single item ?
This is my code but don't work, print empty.

```
QDomDocument doc;
    doc.setContent(reply->readAll());
    QDomNodeList list = doc.elementsByTagName("item");

    qDebug() << "Count" << list.count(); //this list get 39 items from url

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        qDebug() << list.at(i).attributes().namedItem("title").nodeValue();
    }
```

can you help me ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like attribute. It is an element.

```
    QDomDocument doc;
    doc.setContent(reply->readAll());
    QDomNodeList list = doc.elementsByTagName("item");
    qDebug() << "Count" << list.count(); //this list get 39 items from url
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        QDomElement first_title = list.at(i).toElement().firstChildElement("title");
        qDebug() << first_title.text();
    }
```